# for ubuntu my hard drive is a thumbstick i still have my hard drive but it doesnt show it in file system what can i do

Tags: hard-drive

I have my hard drive and i can see it if you go to disks, but when i go to file system i cant find it, that means i cant send files to it and i cant use it. any fix for this problem if there is i really need it and also i formated it to the one to use in Linux type 4 something i forgot. when i see it i cant use it because it says that it has 0 bytes and it shows it as a gray rectangle cube and its also called sdb.

Answer (score 0):

So, the HDD is recognized physically and electronically BUT not as a filesystem. Therefore, I would reboot with a USB loaded with the open source (free) distros, System Rescue http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage or the commercial package PartedMagic https://partedmagic.com/ to then use GParted to completely wipe the HDD and reformat and mount it.

Comment: any free thing like that or is there a way to put something similar for free

Comment: System Rescue is free.